# How to call spring scheduler from UI

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have defined a spring scheduler and it works automatically based on the cron i gave but i would like to call the scheduler from UI so that this scheduler can be run whenever some one wants to run.

```
<bean id="schedulerToCall" class="validPackagename.schedulerToCallTask" />
```

I would like to call this spring bean in some controller manually.

how to call that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example your context config is like this:

```
<bean id="schedulerToCall" class="validPackagename.SchedulerToCallTask" />
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulerToCall" method="runTaskMethod" cron="0 1 0 * * MON"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

In `SchedulerToCallTask.java`:

```
@Component
public class SchedulerToCallTask{
```

In the controller class you can just:

```
@Resource
SchedulerToCallTask schedulerToCallTask;
```

In the controller function you want to call this task:

```
schedulerToCallTask.runTaskMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your query correctly. since cron runs based on the cron parameters, you need to pass the current time in the cron parameter. Also that cron parameters should be passed dynamically when the use want to run.

eg:

```
<task:scheduled ref="cronService" method="runCron" cron="* 0 0 * * ?"></task:scheduled>
```

Comment: street hawk my question is like how to call that class from controller manually? like creating object for class and call the method